# How do I redirect a multi language site to a default language page?

Tags: redirect, web, multilingual

**I have this:**

http://example.com/EN/index.php  - english version

http://example.com/PT/index.php  - portuguese version

**What I want:** *http://example.com/* to be taken to the **portuguse page by default**.

---

I've also been thinking on having the portuguese page on the root and english in the EN/ directory. is this better for SEO?

Comment: oh well, I didn't know where do you draw the line. Do I ask there or wait this to be moved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iam not sure if i understand the problem, but you can create an index.php in your
root and change the header to forward the user to the PT/index.php

Header("Location: ./PT/index.php");

later you can construct an if/else check to verify the language of the browser etc..

Comment: Is this noticeable to the user? Does it work with all the browsers?
Does this have any kind of disadvantages over not having redirect pages?

Comment: Hi, iam not sure how google is reacting on this redirection, but it works on all browsers ;-)